# If I deploy my Network Function on Oracle Virtualbox mean I am following NFV standards

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I am working on a project related to `Network Function Virtualization`. To virtualize my `Network Function`, I am planning to deploy the `Network Function` on an `Oracle Virtualbox`. If I deploy my `Network Function` on the `Oracle Virtualbox`, does that mean I am complying with the standards of [NFV architecture](https://www.telcocloudbridge.com/blog/a-cheat-sheet-for-understanding-nfv-architecture/) according to [ETSI](https://www.etsi.org/).

1. If yes, how `Oracle Virtualbox` is implementing the NFV architecture. Any source documentation would be useful.
2. If no, how much is `Oracle Virtualbox` implementation different from `ETSI` standards and what opensource architecture is better for implementing my project. Any source documentation on how much `Oracle Virtualbox` deviating from `ETSI` standard is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The ETSI NFV Standards do not mandate a specific hypervisor.

As you may see in the [Architectural Framework specification](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/nfv/001_099/002/01.01.01_60/gs_nfv002v010101p.pdf) the MANO (Management and Orchestration) component interacts with the virtualization layer by means of a Virtual Infrastructure Manager (VIM), which decouples from the specific hypervisors.

The requirements for the MANO - VIM interface are [specified here](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/NFV-IFA/001_099/006/02.01.01_60/gs_NFV-IFA006v020101p.pdf).

If you are starting from scratch, you may want to check out [Openstack](https://www.openstack.org/) as a VIM and [OSM](https://osm.etsi.org) as the MANO. Others open source implementation for both components are also available.

Have a look at the [OpenStack VirtualBox drivers](https://docs.openstack.org/ironic/6.2.3/drivers/vbox.html) to get more information.

Installation information for OSM Release 5 are [available here](https://osm.etsi.org/wikipub/index.php/OSM_Release_FIVE).

Comment: From your above answer, deploying my network function on the `Oracle VirtualBox` is not enough to be called as NFV. In addition, I need to install `VIM (Openstack)` and `MANO (OSM)` to be called as NFV. Is my undertstanding correct?

Comment: Correct. Any VIM and any MANO implementing the NFV Interfaces will be valid, I mention those two as examples, other exist that would work as well.

Comment: The problem is my network function is proprietary software that does not have an image to instantiate dynamically through MANO/VIM. I have to deploy my proprietary software only through Oracle VirtualBox VM. Is there any way to integrate my `VirtualBox` with `VIM (OpenStack)`  and `MANO (OSM)`.

Also, what is `OpenStack VirtualBox drivers` used for (why you asked me to look into?)